# Cloud Functions and DeviceCheck, not getting response from Apple

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, devicecheck

I'm testing out DeviceCheck, but I'm occasionally having an issue where I don't receive body, response, or error values from Apple. I'm using `request` to communicate with them. I've tried using `request-promise` and switched to `api.devicecheck.apple` rather than `api.development.devicecheck.apple`, but neither has any effect. I think it has something to do with how crowded a wifi network is, but if so that sucks because my wifi is great even if crowded. I imagine anyone using the app would very likely have the same issue. Is there anything I can do to get any response at all, even if delayed? Some examples are below:

[Normal responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOKTR.png)

```
8:36:28.500 PM
check
IncomingMessage 

8:36:22.101 PM
check
Callback response

8:36:22.101 PM
check
{"bit0":true,"bit1":false,"last_update_time":"2018-09"}

8:36:21.901 PM
check
Callback body:

8:36:20.720 PM
check
Function execution took 14 ms, finished with status: 'ok'

8:36:20.713 PM
check
Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

8:36:20.706 PM
check
Function execution started
```

[Incomplete responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsOsl.png)

```
4:37:55.435 PM
check
Function execution took 436 ms, finished with status: 'ok'

4:37:55.405 PM
check
Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

4:37:55.001 PM
check
Function execution started
```

('check' is the name of the cloud function)

Comment: So your Cloud Function fires properly but isn't getting a response back from your Apple device?

Comment: It sounds like your function isn't properly returning/handling promises correctly.  When this happens, any promise code might get lost and fail to execute.

Comment: @YingLi, I'm not getting a response from Apple's servers. My device/client side triggers the 'check' cloud function, 'check' then sends the device token to Apple. I'm not getting anything from them sometimes.

Comment: @JamesPoag that's what I thought, so I tried request-promise. Same results.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was really simple fortunately, and yeah I wasn't handling the promise properly. For `request-promise`, just needed to add `return` before calling it.

My var was:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
```

Instead of only this:

```
rp(options, callback);
```

I needed this:

```
return rp(options, callback);
```

Thank you guys for your responses :)